# Reactjs append an element instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate through a list/array/object of things: (I used coffeescript to keep it clear, [jsfiddle of full JS here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AMxfL/) but it's just a forEach)

```
pages = for page, each of @props.ids
    $('#start').append("<div id='"+page+"' ></div>")
    React.renderComponent page(title: each.title, text: each.text), $("#"+page)[0]
```

and append each of them, instead of replacing, leaving only the last item in the list.

Where the `#start` element is the starting container, and I want to populate it with multiple elements,  but I need to give each their own container, otherwise they will all overwrite eachother, the default reactjs behaviour.

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell react to append instead of replacing the div.

I'd like to avoid using jquery if possible, and do it purely react-ly.

I though about giving the `React.renderComponent` `page` the initial list, and then iterate in the previously called template, however, then i'm facing a different problem, I have to `return` a reactjs element object, consisting of the whole list, which I really don't prefer.

I need for the initial call to create individual, independent react templates, appending eachother in a list, prefferably without any extra containers, or using jquery.

Answer (score 15):

I think you're getting the concept wrong. React's `renderComponent` indeed renders a single component, somewhere. Doing this multiple times only re-renders the same component at that place (aka idempotent). There's no real "append" statement, at least not in the way you asked for.

Here's an example of what you're trying to achieve. Forgot about `renderComponent` in this. It's just to put the component somewhere.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var pages = [{title: 'a', text: 'hello'}, {title: 'b', text: 'world'}];

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.pages.map(function(page) {
            return <div>Title: {page.title}. Text: {page.text}</div>;
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<App pages={pages} />, whateverDOMNodeYouWantItToBeOn);
```

See what I did there? If I want multiple `div`s, I just create as many as I want to see. They represent the final look of your app, so making a same `div` be "appended" multiple times doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: The reason why I want to append it, is to keep it a seperate component, so I can update or modify each page individually. I need to access the states and willComponentUpdate. Set and get. Tree-like json represents dom, when i change json, dom changes, basically

Comment: It's very easy to do this in React. If you want more help, come to the irc #reactjs channel.

Comment: Is `renderComponent` deprecated?

Comment: Answer's a bit dated, but yes, it's called `React.render` now.

Comment: Actualy now it's `ReactDOM.render`

Answer (score -1):

Create a div with a class extradiv:

```
<div class="extradiv">
  
</div>
```

In CSS, Set It's display to none:

```
.extradiv {
  display: none;
}
.extradiv * {
  display: none;
}
```

In JS implement this function:

```
function GoodRender(thing, place) {
    let extradiv = document.getElementsByClassName('extradiv')[0];
    ReactDOM.render(thing, extradiv);
  extradiv = document.getElementsByClassName('extradiv')[0];
  place.innerHTML += extradiv.innerHTML;
}
```

Than you can use this in place of ReactDOM.render:

```
GoodRender(<Component>My Text</Component>, YourDOMObject)
```