# Why infinite scroll pagination uses useState not using DOM append instead?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have seen many tutorials and articles which use `useState` to store all the records on a state instead of using `ReactDOM` or something to add HTML elements.

For example, they keep previous data and merge with new data and after that set in a `useState` hook

```
return [...new Set([...prevBooks, ...res.data.docs.map(b => b.title)])]
```

#### I have 2 questions

1. Isn't it a performance problem to have all the records in the state and to print it in JSX by map? There may be millions of records.
2. If I want to add a React component to the end of a div#ID, what should we do in the pagination?

##### For example, I have this block code:

```html
<article className="col-sm">
  <div className="row client-home-header-post-article-row" id="BlogsPosts">
    {posts.entries.map((item) => (
      <BlogItem post={item} key={item.id} size={4} />
    ))}
  </div>
</article>
```

And with an action function like `const showMore`, add another `<BlogItem post={item} key={item.id} size={4} />` to the bottom of `BlogsPosts` ID (like e.append)

I saw this post [Append component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846135/6310900), he suggested without recommending to use [`ReactDOM.createPortal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), but I tested it like this, and it does not work

```js
ReactDOM.createPortal(
 <BlogItem post={item} key={item.id} size={4} />, 
 document.querySelector("#BlogsPosts")!
)
```

The posts I saw:

- [Append component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846095)
- [Reactjs append an element instead of replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334104)
- [How do you append a React Component to an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72915876)
- [How to append React components to HTML element using .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899729)
- [How can I append a React component to an html element i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177378)
- [Using document.querySelector in React? Should I use refs instead? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198952)
- [Append Element to an Existing Element React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972941)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it a performance problem to have all the records in the state
> and to print it in JSX by map? There may be millions of records.

It depends. A performant server should try to keep the metadata it returns to the browser for each book small. That is, each book object should try to to contain minimal information like a title, author, price, and thumbnail URL, not **all** the data that the database knows about the book. Something like this:

```
{
   "title":"MyBook",
   "author":"Jeff Bezos",
   "price":19.99,
   "price_unit":"USD",
   "thumbnail":"https://websitename.s4-bucket.region.UUID-1234"
}
```

Reducing the amount of data will boost performance by making searching through this data faster on the browser. Each object of this size is also less than 500 bytes, so if you are obtaining 50 items at a time you're only retrieving 25KB data per request, which with modern speeds only takes a few milliseconds.

> If I want to add a React component to the end of a div#ID, what should
> we do in the pagination?

You can use a `useMemo` hook which will update the `BlogItem` components you have rendered when the posts change. Something like this should work:

```
const blogItems = useMemo(()=>posts.entries.map((item) => (
      <BlogItem post={item} key={item.id} size={4} />
    )), [posts.length])
```

Then in your JSX just do this:

```
<article className="col-sm">
  <div className="row client-home-header-post-article-row" id="BlogsPosts">
    {blogItems}
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi @Shn_Android_Dev, please consider each post of a CMS. You suggested `useMemo`. It is a question for me. I have 20 records in the state now and 10 more are going to be added. This means that all my previous 20 articles or records will be re-rendered. It is true? Because I already called component ‍`BlogItem` 20 times on the page. And still have the state and do not clean it.

Comment: If you want the previous 20 items to be re-rendered, use what you already had written: `[...new Set([...prevBooks, ...res.data.docs.map(b => b.title)])]`. If not, just reset the state. I'm not sure what you are asking.